# 分割統治法を利用した数式についてです。

Tags: アルゴリズム, 数学

分割統治法についてです。
下記画像の再帰的に代入すると4^2 T(n/2)=....4^log2^n T(1)=n^log2^4 T(1)と数式が変化する過程、理由がわかりません。

数学に弱く数学的な知見が不足しているかもしれません。
噛み砕き解説いただけると幸いです。

参照：データ構造とアルゴリズム

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 『データ構造とアルゴリズム』という名前の書籍は複数あるので、著者名や出版社もあわせて書いていただくとより良さそうです :)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13204568523

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「再帰的に代入」という部分が肝です。

この計算過程では `T(n) = 4 T(n/2)` という等式を `T(n)` に対して代入するという操作を繰り返し（再帰的に）行っています。ここでこの等式は任意の `n` について成り立つので、たとえば `T(n/2) = 4 T(n/4)` という風にも使えます。

```
T(n) = 4 T(n/2)
     = 4 × 4 T(n/4) = 4^2 T(n/4)
     = 4^2 × 4 T(n/8) = 4^3 T(n/8)
     = ...
```

また、ある正の整数 `k` を使って `n = 2^k` と表せるとき、つまり `k = log_2(n)` のとき、この代入操作はぴったり `T(1)` になるまで続けることができます。では `T(1)` になるまで何回代入が必要でしょうか？　上の具体例をもとに考えると、ぴったり `log_2(n)` 回だということが分かります。つまり、以下のようになります。

```
T(n) = 4 T(n/2)
     = 4^2 T(n/4)
     = 4^3 T(n/8)
     = ...
     = 4^(log_2(n)) T(1)
```

最後に、`4 = 2^2` なので `4^(log_2(n))` はもっと簡単な式にできます。たとえば教科書の例と違う変形の仕方をすると、下のようにできます

```
4^(log_2(n)) = (2^2)^(log_2(n))
             = 2^(2 log_2(n))
             = 2^(log_2(n^2))
             = n^2
```

よって、`T(n) = n^2 T(1)` になります。

※`n` がちょうど `2^k` のようにあらわせないときはこんな綺麗にはなりませんが、今求めたいのは計算量の漸近的な挙動（オーダー）であり、上か下かどちらかから抑えられれば問題ありません。本当はそこも厳密に議論すべきです。

Comment: 非常にわかりやすい解説ありがとうございます。
ただ2^(log_2(n^2)) = n^2になる理由がわかりませんでした。
これは対数のどのような性質から変形しているのでしょうか。

Comment: @sample さん、それは対数の（素朴な）定義です。たとえば高校数学の教科書では、ある数 q であって、2^q = p となるようなものを log_2(p) と定めているはずです。